# Kstream aggregation offset out of range

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Hi I tried to aggregate events from kafka and do some operation on 10 next events. This is my code:

```
public KStream<String, Bar> apply(KStream<String, Foo> events) {
        return events
                .groupByKey()
                .aggregate(ArrayList::new, (k, v, agg) -> {
                    if (agg.size() == 10) {
                        return new ArrayList<>(List.of(v));
                    }
                    agg.add(v);
                    return agg;
                },
                        Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.ListSerde((Class<ArrayList<Foo>>)(Class<?>)ArrayList.class,
                        Serdes.serdeFrom(new FooSerializer(), new FooDeserializer())))
                )
                .mapValues((foo) -> barDetector.apply(foo))
                .filter((s, bar) -> bar.isPresent())
                .mapValues((s, bar) -> bar.get())
                .toStream()
                .selectKey((s, bar) -> bar.thermometerId());
    }
```

I have the following error when I try to run tests:

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TaskCorruptedException: Tasks [0_0] are corrupted and hence needs to be re-initialized
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StoreChangelogReader.restore(StoreChangelogReader.java:447)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.initializeAndRestorePhase(StreamThread.java:897)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:762)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:604)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:576)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetOutOfRangeException: Fetch position FetchPosition{offset=1, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[localhost:32781 (id: 1 rack: null)], epoch=0}} is out of range for partition anomaly-detector-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000001-changelog-0
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.handleOffsetOutOfRange(Fetcher.java:1418)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.initializeCompletedFetch(Fetcher.java:1370)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:660)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1304)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1238)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1211)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StoreChangelogReader.restore(StoreChangelogReader.java:434)
```

The weird thing is, I wait 5 seconds for test passing, test failing and after that debugger catching logic in barDetector. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you share the test that is causing the issue, and also the stacktrace showing the line of your code that is behind the issue ?